# Correct combination of escape characters to inject PHP in javascript?

Tags: php

I've tried all the combination I know of but can't get it right!

```
echo  <<<EOF

     <a href="javascript:popup('$comments')">Popup!</a>   

EOF;
```

I want to pass the string that is contained in $comments to the popup, but I can't seem to get the right combination of escape characters and concatenation. Help pls!

TIA

Edit: This is the HTML that goes into the string I mentioned.

```
$comments.= "<b>" . $row['comName'] . "</b><br><i>" . $row['comment'] . "</i><br><br>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the string to valid Javascript/JSON first to preserve Javascript syntax, then escape the Javascript to preserve the syntax of the HTML it's embedded in:

```
$js = sprintf('javascript:popup(%s)', json_encode($comments));
printf('<a href="%s">Popup!</a>', htmlspecialchars($js));
```

Since this is quite a pain, you should really try to go for [*unobtrusive Javascript*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_Javascript), which separates Javascript from HTML.

Comment: Thanks, that does look complicated but is still not passing it to the popup.

Comment: What's the resulting HTML?

Comment: Working perfectly now. Instead of printf'ing it I set it as a variable and put that in the EOF field. I'll have a read of that article and see if I can work that method into my workflow. I'm just learning Ajax and JQuery and its leading to some messy code.