# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input in php function

Tags: javascript, php

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

I have checked all the parenthesis and brackets but seems like nothing is missing.

```php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo '<div class="columns '.$row['type'].'">';
    echo '<div class="image" style="background-image: url(images/'.$row['image_tag'].')"></div>';
    echo '<div class="description">';
    echo '<p class="productName">'.$row['name'].'</p>';
    echo '<p class="productDetails">'.$row['details'].'</p>';
    echo '<p class="productPrice"> RM'.$row['price'].'</p>';
    //the line below cause error.
    echo '<button class="addItem" onclick="addToCart("'.$row['name'].'")">Add to cart</button>';
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

```
function addToCart(name){
      console.log(name);
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error?

Comment: Hello, sorry my question was not clear. The onclick function is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should change it from

```
echo '<button class="addItem" onclick="addToCart("'.$row['name'].'")">Add to cart</button>';
```

to

```
echo '<button class="addItem" onclick="addToCart(\''.$row['name'].'\')">Add to cart</button>';
```

Because **$row['name']** returns a string value so it should be wrapped with single quotes (because double quote is used for element attribute definition) in order to pass it as a string value to javascript function.

Comment: Note that this will still break if `$row['name']` contains any quote. You must [escape all values correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15892666/476).

Comment: @deceze escape all values correctly as in $name= sprintf(%s, json_encode($row['name')); ?

Comment: @YKW Yes. Ensure your PHP value has proper Javascript syntax with `json_encode`, then ensure that Javascript value has proper HTML syntax with `htmlspecialchars`. Though that specific `sprintf` call is invalid, I'll assume it's just symbolic in your comment.

Answer (score -1):

---

Try changing:

```
echo '<button class="addItem" onclick="addToCart("'.$row['name'].'")">Add to cart</button>';
```

To:

```
echo '<button class="addItem" '."onclick=\"addToCart('{$row['name']}')\"".'>Add to cart</button>';
```

Comment: Thanks, the second answer works, the last one does not.

Comment: I see, sorry bout that. I deleted it :)